# Cannot add foreign key constraint! porem sintaxe e pks estão corretas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, constraint, chave-estrangeira

Estou a tentar criar uma FK para uma tabela, nao percebo erro de sintaxe, porem o TOAD me devolve a mensagem que nao pode criar a FK.
As tabelas estão criadas no banco, e as PKs estao certas.

```
ALTER TABLE minsarh.perguntas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_perg_perg FOREIGN KEY (id_ds_pergunta) 
 REFERENCES minsarh.tb_ds_pergunta (id_ds_pergunta) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

> Looup Error - MySQK Database Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Nao consigo identificar o erro.

Alguem pode me dar uma idéia????
Obrigado!

Comment: Verifique o nome, tipo e tamanho das PK/FK

Comment: CREATE TABLE minsarh.tb_ds_pergunta (
  `id_ds_pergunta`   int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 ,`ds_pergunta`      varchar(255) NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY (`id_ds_pergunta`)
);

CREATE TABLE `perguntas` (
  `id_pergunta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pergunta`),



Alter Table minsarh.perguntas add CONSTRAINT  fk_perguntas_perg FOREIGN KEY (id_ds_pergunta) 
   REFERENCES  tb_ds_pergunta (id_ds_pergunta) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

Comment: então, 
Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta Wictor, mas 
eu nao consigo identificar diferenças, e ja tentei alterar o nome da constraint, diminuindo e mesmo assim nao aceita.
Eu colei na resposta anterior o script de criacao. caso voce consiga olhar.

Comment: Você criou a FK antes de adicionar a CONSTRANIT?

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na criação das tabelas como colocou nos comentários:

```
CREATE TABLE minsarh.tb_ds_pergunta ( 
    id_ds_pergunta int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    ds_pergunta varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_ds_pergunta) 
); 

CREATE TABLE perguntas ( 
    id_pergunta int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_pergunta), 

Alter Table minsarh.perguntas add CONSTRAINT fk_perguntas_perg FOREIGN KEY (id_ds_pergunta) REFERENCES tb_ds_pergunta (id_ds_pergunta) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Não sei sei tu não colocou toda a criação mas falta fechar o `CREATE TABLE` antes de iniciar o `ALTER TABLE`

Além disso os tipos e tamanhos das PK e FK devem ser iguais na primeira tabela é definido como `INT(11)` e na outra `INT(10)`

Você também está tenando usar uma PK de uma tabela como FK da mesma tabela, isso nem faz sentido

Geralmente FK não são `AUTO-INCREMENT`